# Request entity too large - 413 error IPS 4.3.4

Tags: php, apache, ipb

I am trying to upload a language pack to my forum. When I click upload button I getting error - Request entity too large . This is error 413 . My server is apache. I tried change value client_max_body_size in htaccess file but this does not work.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I deal with it.